# DevExpress PieChart WebChartControl Hover to Highlight Piece of Pie

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress, webchartcontrol

Is there are way to achieve highlighting of the piece of pie when user hover their mouse over the piece of pie like in Chart.Js charts?

I have looked into `ClientSideEvents-ObjectHotTracked` but could not find one to highlight on mouse hover.

`function(s, e) { 
     var hitInPie = e.hitInfo.inSeries; 
     s.SetCursor(hitInPie ? 'pointer' : 'default');
}`

This code is to change the mouse cursor to pointer once it touches series.

What i would like to achieve is highlighting a piece of the pie that the cursor hits.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WebChartControl generates an image on the server side and therefore the Pie segment color cannot be modified using the client-side code only. The Pie segment highlighting feature is not supported by WebChartControl because it will require a round trip to the server.